# Factory reset windows without losing installed files and documents

Tags: windows-7, restore

I have run into serious problems, my System32 files are corrupt and it cannot install new usb devices, I think it's a problem due to messing around with system files and settings. Is there anyway to factory restore the core files without affecting any installed program?

Comment: So you want to reset the system, but not really? Have you tried system restore?

Comment: System restore doesn't have a distant-enough restore point.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have a Repair Install like XP, so I think you are out of luck.  You can copy any files adn documents off of course, but you'll probabaly need to to a reinstall for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a backup of my documents, factory-reset my OS with the backup provided by the system manufacturer, and then restored the backup.

Answer (score 1):

Open an elevated (running as administrator) command prompt and type `sfc /scannow`. This will repair all of the default Windows system files if they are corrupted.

Comment: I already did that.